# How would you say “especially if~” in japanese?

Tags: phrase-requests

For example, what would be a natural way of expressing a sentence like the following:

> I like to go on walks, especially if it’s raining.

Comment: Please give your own attempt at a translation.

Comment: Unrelated hint:  That's more of a "when" than an "if".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, 「特に～」would work best. E.g. 特に雨が降ってるとき or 雨が降ってるときに特に

Comment: Also, a really nice resource: https://www.alc.co.jp/

Comment: Does ときに特に sound a bit funny? In my family someone would probably joke about the similarity of these two standing next to each other.

Comment: ^ Then... how about とき**は**特に instead, maybe? 「雨が降ってるときは特に～～」とか... or maybe 「雨の日は特に～」とか...